# Integrating Google and Facebook login in iOS - AppDelegate openURL

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to integrate facebook and google login into my app but having a problem: Both require the following to be added into the openURL method in the Appdelegate:

```
return [GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                         annotation:annotation]];

return [FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                       openURL:url
                                             sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                    annotation:annotation
         ]]
```

Is there anyway of having these both work together properly. I've looked online but the answers are quite vague and fail to provide a good explanation

**Solution**

Added the following which did the trick for me (as of iOS 9):

```
return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation] || [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation ];
```

Comment: Parse the URL what is sent in the `canOpenURL` delegate method.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: As answered by Maulik, the URL that you are getting in the delegate method, must be different. Just log them to see the difference. You should also try the way as answer given by Maulik.

Answer (score 6):

use following code...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationopenURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplicationannotation:(id)annotation
    {
      if ([FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication])
        return [FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                       openURL:url
                                             sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                    annotation:annotation
         ]];
      else

       return [GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                         annotation:annotation]];
    }
```

another answer..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationopenURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplicationannotation:(id)annotation
{

     NSString *stringURL = [ url absoluteString];
    if([stringURL containsString:@"fb"])
    {


    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
    }
    else
    {
        return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                             annotation:annotation];

    }
}
```

Comment: That code is outdated...I've seen this on a previous answer which unfortunately didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: I used the following code (added in my initial post) that did the trick for me. Your wisdom led me to the answer :)

Comment: and FBAppCall is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Updated Answer

```
func application(
            _ app: UIApplication,
            open url: URL,
            options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
        ) -> Bool {

        let urlString = url.absoluteString
        if urlString.contains("fb"){
            ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                app,
                open: url,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
            )
        }
        else{
            
        }
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
        }
```